# How to concatenate a column with multiple rows into 1?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following data in a spreadsheet and I want: if column 2 = yes, then pull out the data and combine it.

```
Column 1  Column 2
A         Yes
B         Yes
C         Yes
D
E
```

I'm able to get all the data and do the IF function in Google Apps Script and view it in log but would like to combine them into something like this:

```
A; B; C;
```

I'm not sure what codes do I need?

Basically I want if column 2 = yes, pull out column 1, and then combine them.

So I have the following right now:

```
function xyz() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet 1");  
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,rows,2).getValues();

    data.forEach(function(row) { 

    var column1 = row[0];
    var column2 = row[1];

    if (responded === "") {

      var Yes = column1
```

Comment: How can you show them in your console as they currently are?

Answer (score 0):

## A simple transpose and join

```
function concatColumn(column) {
  var column=column || 1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1, column,sh.getLastRow(), 1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    vB[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      vB[j][i]=vA[i][j];
    }
  }
  Logger.log(vB[0].join('; '));
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(vB[0].join('; '));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Transpose and Join');
}
```